# Puppeteer - How to manipulate slider or slider value

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem:** On this hotel website [wyndham](https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/hotels/seattle-wa?brand_id=HR&checkInDate=9/16/2023&checkOutDate=9/17/2023&useWRPoints=false&children=0&adults=1&rooms=1&loc=ChIJVTPokywQkFQRmtVEaUZlJRA&sessionId=1694885169), I am trying to change the `aria-valuemax` of the class `ui-slider-handle` to `200` but I cannot target it.

[image: Wyndham Slider]

My attempts:

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

// * Main Function
let browser;
async function wyndhamScan() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1065, height: 10700 });

    // Go to the URL website
    await page.goto('https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

    // Enter destination
    await page.type('[name="destination"]', 'Chicago, IL, USA' );
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

    // Click Search button
    await page.click('.search-btn.btn-primary');


    // ------------------------------------------ Re-directed to Results page ----------------------------------------
    
}


//! Attempt to manipulate max value of slider
    /*
    const priceSliderSelector = '[class^="ui-slider-range"]';
    const priceSlider = await page.$(priceSliderSelector);

    if (priceSlider) {
        await page.evaluate((priceSlider) => {
            priceSlider.aria-valuemax = constants.MAX_PRICE;
        })
    }


// * Call the main function
(async () => {
    console.log('Starting the Wyndham scraper program...');
    await wyndhamScan()
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        .finally(() => browser?.close());
})();
```

1. 

```
    // Slide Price slider
    /*
    const priceSliderSelector = '[class^="ui-slider-range"]';
    const priceSlider = await page.$(priceSliderSelector);

    if (priceSlider) {
        await page.evaluate((priceSlider) => {
            priceSlider.aria-valuemax = constants.MAX_PRICE;
        })
    }
```

2. 

```
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        // const maxSliderVal = document.querySelector('.price-slider-cmp span.max-slider-val-v2');
        const maxSliderVal = document.querySelector('#pricerangefilter-v2 span[class^="ui-slider-handle"]');
        if (maxSliderVal) {
            console.log(`maxslider max value: is ${maxSliderVal.getAttribute('aria-valuemax')}`);
            maxSliderVal.textContent = maxPrice; // Replace 'New Value' with the value you want
        } else {
            console.log('maxSliderVal element not found');
        }
    });
```

Comment: How this is reproductible? What is `wyndham_constants.js` ? A vanilla `pptr` IS reproductible.

Comment: edited - wydnham_constants.js is not required

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the slider runs via jQueryUI, but it is triggered by dispatching a custom event, which also passes new value, and also updates the UI.

Try this (it should trigger slider to load filtered items, data attributes and slider UI won't change..):

```
// wait for slider to initialize
await page.waitForSelector('#pricerangefilter-v2 span[class^="ui-slider-handle"]', {
    visible: true,
    timeout: 50000
});


// wait for items to load
await page.waitForSelector('property-card', {
    visible: true,
    timeout: 50000
});


// trigger change
await page.evaluate(() => {

    // get min/max values here: `min-value/max-value` attributes
    // document.querySelector('price-slider').getAttribute('max-value');

    // event that triggers filter (UI doesn't get updated, though..)
    const evt = new CustomEvent('srp.filters.priceSlider.selected', {
        detail: {
            value: 90 // your value
        }
    });

    document.querySelector('price-slider').dispatchEvent(evt);

});
```

**edit**

```
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2', timeout: 50000}),
    page.click('.search-btn.btn-primary')
]);


// wait for slider to initialize
await page.waitForSelector('#pricerangefilter-v2 span[class^="ui-slider-handle"]', {
    visible: true,
    timeout: 50000
});


// wait for items to load
await page.waitForSelector('property-card', {
    visible: true,
    timeout: 50000
});


// trigger change
await page.evaluate(() => {

    setTimeout(()=>{

        // get min/max values here: `min-value/max-value` attributes
        // document.querySelector('price-slider').getAttribute('max-value');

        // event that triggers filter (UI doesn't get updated, though..)
        const evt = new CustomEvent('srp.filters.priceSlider.selected', {
            detail: {
                value: 90 // your value
            }
        });

        document.querySelector('price-slider').dispatchEvent(evt);
        
    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: It would be great to know how you investiguate

Comment: @GillesQuénot well, the first attempt failed, so.. waiting for some feedback to see if it actually works. It's definitely jQuery UI slider, but then I realized it couldn't be triggered via its' API, so I went digging deeper, and found this..

Comment: How you know it's generated bu JQuery UI ?

Comment: @GillesQuénot I saw methods typical for JQ plugins: https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/. I think it's actually a combination of Angular component that handles events, and then passes them to jQuery slider

Comment: I guess you are full stack or front developer ^^ I'm more backend side, so I know less what is used.

Comment: @GillesQuénot well, in this case it comes down to backend, because the trick is to trigger the event in the right moment, after the list is populated, and the slider UI doesn't change, although I don't think it should matter that much..

Comment: I tested your code but unfortunately, the slider didn't get manipulated.

Comment: what about the items, are they updated and filtered to contain only those below the passed in price, as in, the price is under 90 (or some other value you passed). because the filter seems to serve to load items below the passed price

Comment: try the updated code, note `page.click('.search-btn.btn-primary')` is moved. I guess maybe the event is fired before the items are loaded.. so I've added some extra timeout

Comment: @traynor - your code returns `Error: No element found for selector: .search-btn.btn-primary`

Comment: strange.. try just the code with timeout within `page.evaluate`. also, are the items in the list filtered by the passed in value in any case?

Comment: regarding [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77136301/puppeteer-search-results-page-doesnt-load-consistently), yes, I've noticed that page doesn't work sometimes, but only with puppeteer, so there could be some protection

Comment: Looks like the code with just page.evaluate works! You might want to edit your answer to just include the `page.evaluate` portion

Comment: both versions work for me. can you change `await page.goto('https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });` to `await page.goto('https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham', { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });` and then run both versions