# Puppeteer - Search Results page doesn't load consistently

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem:** I am trying to use Puppeteer to webscrape [a hotel website](https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham) but the search **results do not load consistently**.
Does the website have some anti-webscraping defences?

[image: results sometimes just don't load]

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2
const {setTimeout} = require("node:timers/promises");

const url = "https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham";

const navClick = async (page, sel) => {
  const nav = page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.click(sel);
  return nav;
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.type('[name="destination"]', "Chicago, IL, USA");
  await navClick(page, ".search-btn.btn-primary");
  const el = await page.waitForSelector("#chk-show-avail");
  await page.waitForFunction(`
    !document.querySelector("#chk-show-avail").disabled
  `);
  await el.evaluate(el => el.click());

  // not part of the logic; temporarily added so you can see
  // the box was ticked (screenshots can be hidden by modals)
  await setTimeout(60_000);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

I've tried using different UserAgent settings and not blocking any resources but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Showing us your code at this point is less useful than showing the inconsistent scraper responses.

Comment: @selfagency The code seems pretty important. Without it, there's no way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: regarding [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118914/puppeteer-how-to-manipulate-slider-or-slider-value/77119926#comment135983873_77119926), yes, the page doesn't load with puppeteer when accessing after a few times.. (there are multiple errors in the dev tools, especially `Failed to fetch` error, which seems to be the request that creates the list, it just stops..)